# Installing tcnative-1.dll

Tags: iis, tomcat

I am configuring Apache to run on an IIS server. The one requirement that I have left is to install the Tomact Native DLL. I have downloaded tcnative-1.dll from the Apache site. The instructions aren't clear on where I put this file on the web server. How do I install the DLL on the IIS server?

Thanks

Comment: the Tomcat Native Library does not related to IIS & Tomcat integration

Answer (score 2):

The official guide says:

> Edit $CATALINA_BASE\bin\setenv.bat
> (creating the file if necessary) and
> add the path to the tc-native
> libraries, apr and OpenSSL to PATH.
> For example:
>
> ```
> set PATH=%PATH;C:\cygwin\home\support\tomcat-native-current-win32-src\jni\native\Debug;C:\cygwin\home\support\tomcat-native-current-win32-src\jni\apr\Debug;C:\OpenSSL\lib\VC
> ```

And this means: add "C:\cygwin\home\support\tomcat-native-current-win32-src\jni\native\Debug" to the environment variable "PATH", so i believe that is where you should put this file.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to put it into Tomcat's `bin` directory.